# How to create custom boot animation in android 2.3.3

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I want to create a custom bootanimation in android.I have `bootanimation.zip` file that was in `data-->Local folder` but after booting emulator only block screen display.

Kindly help.

Comment: Hello, Swati have you progressed on this, I am also stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't boot animations go into `/system/media` of the device instead?

Comment: there is an error occured:                                  [2012-10-06 11:29:34 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system
[2012-10-06 11:29:34] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

Comment: how can i use adb shell? can you have any example? please help